# How to get all posts except posts that belong to specific post type Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

For example, I register 3 post type (or more) in my theme by `register_post_type()` function:

- Agenda
- Download
- Product

Now I want to get all posts that not belong to `Product` post type (all posts of Post, Page, Agenda, Download).

I don't want to use `'post_type' => array('post','page','agenda','download')` because maybe I will register more post types in the future.

Isn't there no equivalent parameter to `'category__not_in'` for post-types?

Comment: Show your code? What have you attempted so far? Are you using a WP_Query?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28084/exclude-category-from-get-posts

Comment: @yivi Now i'm writing plugin for generate data test automatic. I using ACF in my theme. In this case i have to detect post type that ACF showing. I will try with your comment below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what are attempting is a great idea, but you could do something like this:

First, you [get all the existing](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) post_types:

```
$post_types = get_post_types(['public' => true]);
```

Then, you remove from that array the post types you don't want to query:

```
$excluded_posttypes = ['product'];
$post_types         = array_diff($post_types, $excluded_posttypes);
```

And then you use that as a parameter for your WP_Query call:

```
'post_type' => $post_types,
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try with this way.

Comment: @Mít Did it work? Remember to accept an answer if it solves your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'll need this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

There's an example for excluding categories, maybe this could work with post types.

In case it's not possible with the hook above, you could try the following before building your query:

1. Collect all the post types in your website: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types
2. Put them in an array so you'll be able to use that in your query for the 'post_type' option
3. Remove the post types that you want to exclude from the array

This way every newly registered post type will be included in the query. Take note that the default WP post type 'posts' will also be returned in the `get_post_types` function.

Comment: Thanks for reply. You have the same idea with first comment so i will try both ^^